# iOS -custom xib file not appearing as inputAccessoryView of UITextField

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uiview, interface-builder

I'm following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xP7YvdlnHfA) (except im linking the custom view in code not in IB), but I'll explain what's happening. I have created a custom view that extends off UiView. It is created from an `xib` file. Here is a photo of the `xib` file in interfacebuilder:

[image]

Notice that the file owner is already linked to my custom class.

Now I'll show you my custom class:

```
#import "CostcoLoginView.h"

@implementation CostcoLoginView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CostcoLoginView" owner:self options:nil];

    [self addSubview:self.view];
    }
    return self;
}




@end
```

And here is the header file for my custom view:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CostcoLoginView : UIView
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *view;



@end
```

notice the one property I have: it's a view that is linked to the interfacebuilder `xib` file shown in the photo above.

Everything looks good so far. My goal now is to use this custom UIView as the `inputAccessoryView` of a `UITextField` I have. Here is the partial code:

```
 usernameField.inputAccessoryView = [[CostcoLoginView alloc] init ];
```

Why is this not working? Nothing appears. Is it because of how I'm initializing the custom view? When I check in the simulator nothing appears. I tried toggling the keyboard but nothing appears. The rest of app works fine, but my custom view does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not add subview when you call init,and you forget to set frame of your view in xib.
so you may change your code to this and try.

```
 #import "CostcoLoginView.h"

@implementation CostcoLoginView

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self){
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}


-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{

    self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self){
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setup{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CostcoLoginView" owner:self options:nil];
    self.view.frame  = self.bounds;
    [self addSubview:self.view];
}

@end
```